DC DC buck circuit blows/short circuits
I'm designing a circuit board that has a 24V to 5V DC DC buck circuit. Using TI's power designer, I selected the LMR51450SDRR and copied the exact schematics from the TI website.

Here is the layout:

After the boards arrived, I tested the DC DC circuit on two different boards, using different parts on both. The LMR51450 chip blew on both boards (sharp cracking sound, spark, a tiny flame). The soldering looks fine to me. What could be the issue？

Besides the obvious AGND connection missing, did you solder the PGND connection to the bottom of the chip? Also there seems to be just only one ground via for the whole top ground plane visible, I wonder what route there is from regulator to input or output caps? The ground connection to regulator is just one wide track instead of a plane. The component placement could be much better. Also from where the 24V comes? Purely by mating two connectors, the inrush current and stray inductance may spike the input to damaging levels.

Do you have a ground plane? Why is everything so far spaced out?

You say you copied the exact schematic but the datasheet shows AGND connected to Rfbb (R11 in your schematic). In addition, you are ignoring several of the layout guidelines which are critical for switching converters:

Feedback voltage divider should be placed close to the FB pin
Similarly, the bootstrap capacitor should be placed as close as possible to the BOOT pin, see the recommended layout on the datasheet
The loop enclosed by the SW pin, the inductor, and C20/C21 should be as small as possible; yours is unnecessarily large and surrounds your feedback network
Input capacitors should be placed as close as possible to the chip
According to the datasheet, PG must be left floating if it is unused. I don't see how this is different from pulling it up to Vout with 100k like you've done but that's what the datasheet says
Please use copper pours on multiple pins shorted together instead of blobbing a huge trace on top of them
You will need more heatsinking than what you have now. You need thermal vias to a bottom-layer copper pour and more copper close to the EP on the top side


Gotcha, this is my first time using DC-DCs and I didn't know about these things. Thank you so much!

The first thing that immediately stands out is that your AGND pin is floating. This is the analog ground and should be tied to power ground (ideally with something like a small net tie). With it floating, the analog circuitry likely just isn't working. There might be some other current paths, as well as inaction of protection circuitry, in the absence of this connection that causes the part to blow up. At the minimum, try to bridge pin 8 to GND with a short wire.

Just tried that. Bigger spark. I'm gonna try a different chip

You should start with a lower input voltage to try to eliminate possible overshoots, instead of going straight to 24V.
